# In which cases a question is not anymore available in the review queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/9183) in the "Review Reopen Votes" queue is shown as not anymore available, even if just a user reviewed it, and it has not been re-opened.

The question has been temporary locked by a moderator because a content dispute.

[image: screenshot]

For [this other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/10044), the review is said to be completed.

[image: screenshot]

In which cases a single review causes a question to be not anymore available in the review queue?

Comment: Well, if a question gets locked, it's kind of not possible for a user to cast a reopen vote anymore, so it makes sense that it would get kicked out of the review queue no matter what the review state was... Are you suggesting it get re-added to the queue when it gets unlocked?

Comment: Actually, it was a more generic question. I have edited to hopefully make that clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways a review item can be knocked out of the queue, and many are queue specific. In the Reopen Queue, for example, an item can become no longer reviewable if

- the question is deleted
- the question is reopened
- the question is locked
- all the reopen votes "age" away

In this particular case, the post became unreviewable when it was locked.